# The size of a particular subset of $\mathcal{O}_K$

Tags: proof-verification, algebraic-number-theory

Let $\mathcal{O}_K$ be the ringer of integers of a number filed $K$ of degree $n$ over $\mathbb{Q}$, with integral basis $\{\omega_1, \ldots, \omega_n\}$. Let $\mathfrak{a}$ be an integral ideal of $\mathcal{O}_K$. It is stated in Murdy and Esmonde's book *Problems in Algebraic Number Theory* that the set
$$
S = \left\{s \in \mathcal{O}_K \mid s = \sum_{i = 1}^n m_i\omega_i, \quad m_i \in \mathbb{Z}, \quad 0 \le m_i < (N(\mathfrak{a}))^{1/n}+1 \right\}
$$
contains at least $N(\mathfrak{a})+1$ elements. I am having a hard time seeing this. I feel like there should be some geometric intuition behind this claim (viewing $N(\mathfrak{a})$ as the volume of a parallelepiped) but I'm not sure why we're taking the $n$-th root here.

Comment: The nth root is taken because volumes scale like the nth power of lengths.

Comment: But then why is $|S|\ge N(\mathfrak{a}) +1$? Are we counting each element in $\mathcal{O}_K/\mathfrak{a}$? Where is the $+1$ coming from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The number of $m_i$ is $\lfloor N(\mathfrak{a})^{\frac{1}{n}}\rfloor +1$ multiplying all together we get 
$$(\lfloor N(\mathfrak{a})^{\frac{1}{n}}\rfloor +1)^n \leq |S|$$
Now 
$$N(\mathfrak{a})=( N(\mathfrak{a})^{\frac{1}{n}} )^n<(\lfloor N(\mathfrak{a})^{\frac{1}{n}}\rfloor +1)^n$$
Note the strict inequality: this gives you the extra $+1$.